# События в Python: вызвать foo по нажатию мыши в PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.x, события, pyqt4

Есть такая задачка:

- Python 2.7.2
- PyQT4
- Файл `helloworld.pyw` цепляет интерфейс `editor.ui` с помощью волшебного слова `widget = uic.loadUi("editor.ui")`
- В интерфейсе есть `widget.lcdNumber_3`, у которого есть `mousePressEvent`
- По срабатыванию `mousePressEvent` нужно выполнить, допустим, `def foo(): i=123`

Лазаю по форумам, там все умные вопросы задают, а на такой элементарный ответа не могу найти. Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, нашел. Решение оказалось наитупейшее.

1. Пишем функцию

   ```
   dev foo(ev):
   i=123
   ```
2. Присваиваем `widget.lcdNumber_3.mousePressEvent = foo`.
3. ВСЁ! В функции `foo` мы имеем ещё и параметры эвента.